# Delete index from Elastic Search causes Forbidden error 403

Tags: nest, elasticsearch

While deleting index from Elastic Search, I am getting a HTTP error: 403. The code for deleting index is as follows:

```
static void DeleteIndex(string indexName)
    {
        // Delete index, recreate
        if (_client.IndexExists(desc => desc.Index(indexName)).Exists)
        {
            var response = _client.DeleteIndex(desc => desc.Index(indexName));
            if (!response.IsValid)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.ConnectionStatus);
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
```

Any pointers to how to remove the forbidden error?

Comment: This is an intermittent issue. It happens when the index is in use.